# Отличие MVP от MVC

Tags: ооп, шаблоны-проектирования

В чем состоит принципиальное отличие паттерна MVC (`Model-View-Controller`) от MVP (`Model-View-Presenter`). Когда нужно использовать именно MVP? Прочел несколько статей, но так и не стала ясна разница между контроллером и презентатором.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Очень красиво. Если следовать этим картинкам, то отличие MVP от MVC в том, что функции изменения View из Model переезжают в Controller (и активизируются из Model), который переименовывается в Presenter.

Answer (score 18):

> MVP применяется при создании
> десктопных интерфейсов. Выделяют три
> комопнента: есть модель – группа
> классов, которые отдают данные или
> получают команды, представление –
> форма обладающая состоянием и
> некоторым поведением. Презентер
> создают для отделения бизнес-логики от
> деталей GUI-фреймворка. **В отличие от
> MVC в MVP представление определяет
> презентер, а не наоборот.**

[Model-View-Presenter и сопутствующие паттерны](http://www.rsdn.ru/article/patterns/ModelViewPresenter.xml) - очень подробно с примерами и диаграмами расписано. В самом конце есть именно про отличия.