# Различие между паттернами MVC и MVP

Tags: mvc, архитектура, шаблоны-проектирования, mvp

В чём состоит различие между паттернами  MVC и MVP? В каких случаях лучше использовать каждый из них?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Отличие MVP от MVC](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/58377/%d0%9e%d1%82%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%b5-mvp-%d0%be%d1%82-mvc)
 [Подробности из ответа.](https://habr.com/ru/post/215605/)